# make a table raw blink when scrolled to

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have added a smooth scroll animation to a page that host a table were i get a link to scroll one of the rows from another page, however its not very clear whish row is been scrolled so i was wondering if there is a way to make that row blink few times after the scroll animation so the user knows exactly were to look.

```
    html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
```

I have seen this done somewhere previously with an arrow pointing at the section however I don't remember the website.

Comment: How is the row addressed, by ID? Can you share some example HTML and an example of the link?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a complete example, I added the URI handling after your comment

Change

```
const url = new URL("https://example.com/index.html?x=YOURIDHERE"); // new URL(location.href);
```

to

```
const url = new URL(location.href);
```

on your real page

```js
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
  const url = new URL("https://example.com/index.html?x=YOURIDHERE"); // new URL(location.href);
  const tr = document.getElementById(url.searchParams.get("x"))
  if (tr) {
    tr.scrollIntoView();
    tr.classList.add("selected")
    setTimeout(function() {
      tr.classList.remove("selected")
    }, 4000);
  }
})
```

```css
html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

table {
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border: 3px solid purple;
}

tr {
  border: 3px solid purple;
}

@keyframes selected {
  from {
    background-color: red;
  }
  to {
    background-color: inherit;
  }
}

.selected {
  animation: selected 1s infinite;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Row</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="YOURIDHERE">
      <td>Blinking row here</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: in your example you are using id="blink" where the blink is going to happen however in my case i need the blink to happen based on the section in the url for example http://x.x/index.html#xx then the blink happens at the <tr id=xx> .......

Comment: i found a solution using your code by adding 

function getUrlVars() {
    var vars = {};
    var parts = window.location.href.replace(/[?&]+([^=&]+)=([^&]*)/gi, function(m,key,value) {
        vars[key] = value;
    });
    return vars;
}
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
  const tr = document.getElementById(getUrlVars()["x"])
  tr.scrollIntoView();
  tr.classList.add("selected")
  setTimeout(function() {
    tr.classList.remove("selected")
  }, 4000)
})

Comment: Blink was and example ID of course! Could be anything and of course taken from the url but I did not have that information at the time of coding

Comment: @Themodmin See my update after you clarified my inquiry into how you got the ID of the row into the script.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Mplungjan this has got me 99% to what I wanted I have only added a small addition to get the parameter from the URL, you can use a link with a parameter to the section id like `https://example.com/index.html?x=YOURIDHERE`

```js
   function getUrlVars() {
    var vars = {};
    var parts = window.location.href.replace(/[?&]+([^=&]+)=([^&]*)/gi, function(m,key,value) {
        vars[key] = value;
    });
    return vars;
}
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
  const tr = document.getElementById(getUrlVars()["x"])
  tr.scrollIntoView();
  tr.classList.add("selected")
  setTimeout(function() {
    tr.classList.remove("selected")
  }, 4000)
})
```

```css
html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

table {
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border: 3px solid purple;
}

tr {
  border: 3px solid purple;
}

@keyframes selected {
  from { background-color: red;   }
  to   { background-color: inherit; }
}

.selected {
  animation: selected 1s infinite;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    
    <tr id="1">
      <td>Row</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="2">
      <td>Row</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="3">
      <td>Row</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="4">
      <td>Row</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="5">
      <td>Row</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="6">
      <td>Row</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="7">
      <td>Row</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="8">
      <td>Row</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="9">
      <td>Row</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="10">
      <td>Row</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="11">
      <td>Row</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="12">
      <td>Row</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="13">
      <td>Row</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="14">
      <td>Row</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="15">
      <td>Row</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="16">
      <td>Row</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="17">
      <td>Row</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="18">
      <td>Row</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="19">
      <td>Row</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="20">
      <td>Row</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="21">
      <td>Row</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="22">
      <td>Row</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```